# How to create blob URL for large videos

Tags: url, blob

I am using below javascript code to create blob URL. If video size is more like(500mb), then it is taking lot of time.

Please help me to create blob URL for large videos

if we can see Youtube the videos are playing very fast even though they are big in size with BLOB URL

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blob URL</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <video controls="" preload="auto" id="_video"></video>
        <script>

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';

            xhr.onload = function() {

              var reader = new FileReader();

              reader.onloadend = function() {
               //console.log(atob(reader.result.slice(reader.result.indexOf(',') + 1)));
                var byteCharacters = atob(reader.result.slice(reader.result.indexOf(',') + 1));

                var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);



                for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {

                  byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
                  //console.log(i);
                }

                var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'video/mp4'});
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                document.getElementById('_video').src = url;

              }

              reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);

            };

            xhr.open('GET', 'domain.com/738-360p.mp4',true);

            xhr.send();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why aren't you just connecting the video src directly to the original url?

Comment: after creating blob URL i am assigning it to video src